# Finding and deleting text cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to clear up a table. I have 0 coding experience, so bear with me. I want the macro to do the following:

- Find all cells containing "USANN" in columns A:C
- Delete all cells containing "USANN"
- Shift cells up

The code either does nothing or only works on the first cell, i.e. doesn't loop.

I've tried a range of different codes found online, but they all only delete the first cell with the correct value. Any help is appreciated :) It also seems like most codes are designed to delete the entire row, not just the cell, which isn't what i'm trying to do.

Comment: It would be advisable to - at least - post also the code that is not working. In this way no effort is shown and very likely the question will be closed after being down-voted multiple times.

Comment: Record a macro while performing the task in Excel. This will generate the corresponding code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Find` and `FindNext`, and a `Do` loop.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = ActiveSheet.Range("A:C").Find( _
                   What:="USANN", _
                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                   LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    Do While Not cell Is Nothing
        cell.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Set cell = Range("A:C").FindNext()
    Loop
End Sub
```